# DoctrineExtension Sluggable doesn't work with id field

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, stofdoctrineextensions

I am trying to setup Sluggable from StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle to generate slug based primary key id and name field

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"id","name"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

However It doesn't generate like id-name, only generates slug based name. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

If your **sluggable listener** listens on Doctrine's **prePersist** operation ...

... then your entity does at that point not have an id because it was not yet persisted.

This explains the missing *id* in the slug.

Set SluggableListener to **postPersist** and it will work as desired.

Change [Gedmo/Sluggable/SluggableListener](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/SluggableListener.php#L74)'s subscribed events to postPersist.

Comment: I understond it, I tried writing my own SluggableListener but no success, Could you provide an example?

Comment: The problem with using entity "ids" in slug is that you'll need 2 requests to create an object instead of one.

Comment: you can't avoid that as long as you're using auto-generated ID's

Comment: @nifr postPersist no such function exist on the listener